# Using an app to link directly to a specific photo album

Tags: facebook, iframe, hyperlink

This is the situation:

- I got a photo album
- I made an app with an icon that needs to link directly to the album, without first having to navigate to Photo's > Album.

Is this possible?

I tried to enter the full url (http://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.203369709718789.58552.202010919854668) in the 'Page Tab URL' section, but obviously, now when you click the tab, Facebook tries to load the entire Facebook website inside the iFrame.
Not a good idea..

So basicly I would like to know if there is a direct link to the frame that holds this specific URL.
Is there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think i fully understand your question...
If you want to link a page tab to a different url - what you might want to try doing is pointing that tab url to a page on your server that serves a javascript redirect.  Here is how it looks in php :

```
echo "<script language=javascript>";
echo "top.location.href = '".$url."';";
echo "</script>";
```

That is all that the page will do.
So... by clicking the page tab you will see a blank tab and immediately be redirected to the desired url.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!

However, I would like to link to a facebook photo album. Is this possible? Because I can't figure out the direct link to the frame holding that album.

I hope this is a better explanation? :-)

If not, I'll throw in some screenshots to illustrate it!

Comment: what do you mean by frame? If you can navigate to the album - then you just copy the url from there.  As long as the user has permissions to see that content the url should work.

Comment: Well, this is what happends: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/535/schermafbeelding2011090s.png/

So as you can see, it's loading Facebook INSIDE Facebook. Or something liket that. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: ok alex, i can see what you mean.. what you need to do is place that javascript i posted before - the key here is the "top.location.href" - this will tell your browser not to open the page inside facbook - but instead simply send the user to the link that you want.

Comment: Ah great, thanks! At this moment I just filled out the link to the album in the Page Tab URL section at the developers page. Should I change that to a different one at my own server and insert the javascript? Thanks again man!

Comment: exactly! yes! thats what you should do! If it works for you, please mark this question as answered! :)

Comment: Woohoo, that worked just great! Thanks for the great help! P.S. Where can I mark this question as answered? :-)

Comment: :D at the top of my answer there should be the number zero with two arrows - bellow that there is a "check mark" - you press the check mark to declare the answer.

Comment: Haha, missed that one. Thanks